# Autostart JavaFX Application on RaspberryPi

Tags: linux, javafx-2, javafx, raspberry-pi

I programmed a JavaFX application which runs on a "Raspberry Pi" (a small ARM based Linux Computer). The OS on the "Pi" is "Raspbian" (a Debian Linux for Raspberry Pi). I installed JDK8 on Raspbian to run graphic JavaFX Application without X-Server. This all works fine :) I can start the Application by entering the following command:

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -cp /home/pi/sqljdbc4.jar:/home/pi/Leitwarte.jar leitwarte.Leitwarte
```

When the application starts it takes full control over mouse an keyboard, so there is no way back into console, but this doesent maters because it is just a monitoring system an i am able to shut the mashine down over ssh.

I now want to start the application directly after booting, so that there is no need for entering username ,passwort and starting the application.

The mashine does nothing else just running the app (of course there runs a ftp, ssh deamon for making updating the app posible)

Please tell me step by step, because i dont work with Linux for a long time.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMD

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo nano leitwarte
```

Enter the following

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/leitwarte

touch /var/lock/leitwarte

case "$1" in
start)
echo "Starting Leitwarte ... "
/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -cp /home/pi/sqljdbc4.jar:/home/pi/Leitwarte.jar leitwarte.Leitwarte > /dev/null &
;;
stop)
echo "Killing Leitwarte ..."
killall java
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/leitwarte {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

then

```
chmod 755 leitwarte
update-rc.d leitwarte defaults
```

DONE

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem

> When the application starts it takes full control over mouse an
>   keyboard, so there is no way back into console

by adding quotes ("") and by giving `-Djavafx.platform=gtk` for `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS`. 
For example in my case I replaced this code:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-XX:+UseG1GC -Dmode=prod_w_updates
```

to this:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-XX:+UseG1GC -Dmode=prod_w_updates -Djavafx.platform=gtk"
```

Hope, it will help