# Hardware+OS setup for an Application

Tags: linux, javafx, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, barcode-scanner

I want to make a system which would get input from USB barcode scanner, validate it on remote server and display an answer (text and images).
I would use JavaFX or in-browser JS web application to grab scanner input somehow.
I'm planning to run this application on Raspberry Pi or plain PC.

Is there a way (or a special linux distribution) to ensure that system always loads the same way and starts JavaFX app or opens particular web page in browser?
e.g. no login page, NO update or other popups are shown.

Any other ideas? Thanks
**...**

Found an interesting solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139014/autostart-javafx-application-on-raspberrypi?rq=1), where JavaFX GUI app is started from command line, without X-Server(linux graphical interface) at all.

Comment: You should read [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/), I particularly recommend [Chapter 7. Setting Up System Bootscripts](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter07/introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done something similar, and it's not too hard. Obviously working on the Pi, you will want to use something like Linux and having limited hardware will mean that you should be minimising what you are running. Due to this, I would recomend that you run a light weight distro. Something like arch (which is what I used) allows you to build only what you want from the ground up without the need to find and compile everything like you do for LFS or Gentoo.

As for booting, the following two wikis will give you the details of starting the Gui without manual login: 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Login

After that, it is simply a matter of putting the command to launch your program in .xinitrc.